# Ubuntu 16.04 takes long time to boot using btrfs and persistent logs

Tags: boot, btrfs

I am using `btrfs` filesystem and I've created `/var/log/journal directory` to have persistent logs. But Ubuntu 16.04 started to take so much time to boot.

I've ran `systemd-analyze plot > boot.svg` in my home directory and opened up the image and saw that `systemd-journal-flush.service` was taking the blame with about 50 seconds.

What should I do to speed the boot up?`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/fc68c92973e5437ee0489c1bc80d80f0a7b6ca0b) systemd commit, btrfs's copy-on-write (COW) slows down journal access.

One can disable the COW on the journal directory to fix the slow journal access times.

Here is how I did:

Stop journald service as we'll move its directory.

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-journald
```

Move the journal

```
sudo mv /var/log/journal /var/log/journal-1
```

Create new journal directory

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/journal
```

Disable COW on the new journal directory. The command only works for the files created after the command.

```
sudo chattr +C /var/log/journal
```

Move the journal back

```
sudo cp -a /var/log/journal-1/* /var/log/journal
```

Remove the old directory

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/journal-1
```

Restart systemd-journald

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-journald
```

You can `cd` into the `/var/log/journal/` and run lsattr to check if you disabled COW. The last big C means that COW has been disabled.